# Alert firing after any change - how to make it fire only after the value has changed in the below fields

Tags: jquery, alert

I am new to coding and I have a question about my code. Currently, the alert pops up whenever there is a change in any field on the form, but I want it to only pop up when a specific field is changed. How can I make the alert field-specific? Here is my code (JQuery):

```js
YesNoAnswers();

$('#case-action-container select').select2().on('change', function(e){
  YesNoAnswers();
});

$('#case-action-container .form-input input').on('change', function(e){
  YesNoAnswers();
});

function YesNoAnswers(){
  if ($('select.breath_reading_1').val() =="Second reading not required" ) {
    alert("X");
  } else if ($('select.breath_reading_1').val() =="Second reading required" ) {
      alert("X");
  }
  if ($('select.sample_measured_within_range_32__38c').val() =="No - screen invalid (see SOP instructions)" ) {
    alert("X");
  }

  if ($('select.amphetamines_amp').val() =="Non-neg" ) {
    alert("Non-negative sample.");
  }
};
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.